# Database with support for JOINs and a flexible data schema

Tags: database

For our project, we need a database that supports JOINs and has the ability to easily add and modify attributes of the entity (schema-less/free). Key points:

- The system is designed to work with customers (CRM)
- Basic entities: User, Customer, Case, Case Interaction, Order
- Currently in the database there are ~200k customers and ~250k orders
- Customer entity contains 15-20 optional attributes that are most often not filled
- About 100 new cases a day
- The data is synchronized with several other sources in the background

Requirements (high to low priority):

1. Ability to implement search/sort by related entities, e.g. Case by linked Customer name (support JOINs)
2. Having the flexibility to change the schema of the data and do not store NULL for a large number of attributes
3. Performance
4. ORM for Python with support for monitoring changes and the possibility of storing only the changes to the database

What we've tried:

- MongoDB does not satisfy paragraph 1.
- PostgreSQL with all the attributes in one table does not satisfy paragraph 2.
- PostgreSQL with a separate table for each attribute or EAV does not satisfy paragraph 3 (a lot of slow joins), but seems a better solution than others.

Can you suggest any database or design of the system that will meet our needs?

Answer (score 1):

Datomic might be worth checking out (http://www.datomic.com/). It satisfies requirements 1-3, and although there's no python ORM, there is a REST API.

Datomic is based on an Entity Attribute Value schema (it's not quite schema free - you need to specify a name and type for each attribute -  but any entity can have any attribute). It is transactional and has support for joins, unlike some of the other flexible "NoSQL" solutions. Interestingly, it also has first-class support for time (e.g. what is the history of this entity/what did the database look like at time t,etc), which might be useful if you're tracking cases and interactions.

Queries are based on datalog, which queries by unification. Query by unification looks a bit odd at first but is brilliant once you get used to it.

For example,  a query to find cases by linked customer name would be something like this:

```
[find ?x
 :in $
 :where [?x :case/linked-customers ?c
         ?c :customer/name "Barry"]]
```

The query engine looks in the database, and tries to satisfy the where clause by unifying all occurrences of a given variable. In this case, only `?c` appears twice (the case has a linked customer c whose name is Barry), but queries can obviously get a lot more complex. The `$` here represents the database.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider storing the "flexible" part as XML. Some databases, e.g. DB2, allow XML indexing so lookup performance should be as good as with the relational data store. DB2 Express-C is free and does not have an artificial limit on the database size.

**Update** Since 2015 DB2 Express-C limits the database user data volume to 15 TB, which still should be plenty.